# How to change session attribute value without using form fields

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, jboss

In my knowledge we can use hidden form fields to change session values by manipulating hidden form field values using JavaScript. My question is can we do same without using hidden form fields. I searched for this and i don't find a answer for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please specify / show your code, what you have tried, and then answers can be suggested on that.

Comment: @MandarPandit thanks for comment, But do you understand my question? It is not at all related to one code.

Answer (score 2):

It's depending on which technology have you used. For example, if you have used Java web technologies, you can change session attribute value through Servlet's `doGet` or `doPost` method, like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String someAttr = (String)request.getAttribute("someAttr");
    someAttr = "New value";
    session.setAttribute("someAttr", someAttr);
}
```

I hope this would help!

Comment: Thanks for answer,but i want to do same on client side(browser).based on user action.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [JSP JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) to change the attribute set in any scope if not found in that scope then it will create a new one.

For example

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
...
<c:set var="name" value="FaizAli" scope="session"/>
```

Read more about [J2EE 1.4 Tutorial - Using JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html)